# CSS Set Colour Depending on Another Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, joomla3.0

I have a number of html elements on my page, for example;

```
<section id="top-bar">
  <!-- html content -->
</section>

<section id="header">
  <!-- html content -->
</section>

<div id="left">
  <!-- html content -->
</div>

<section id="footer">
  <!-- html content -->
</section>
```

The CSS `background-colour` and `text-colour` for these `sections` are set in the Joomla 3.x Template settings, this is my 'Brand Colour' - see the image below.

[image]

If I choose `Preset 1` in the template settings then `preset1.css` is loaded in the website front end, if I select `Preset 2` then `preset2.css` is loaded in the website front end etc.

My issue is that I have other *custom elements* on the page (e.g. `<div id="left">` in the code above). The background colour and text colour for these elements aren't set or controlled via the template settings, instead I have to manually set these in a `custom.css` file, which works, however I have to change this `custom.css` file to every time I change my 'Brand Colour'.

Basically, I'd like my *custom elements* to take on the same 'Brand Colours' that I specify in the template configuration. WIthout me having to change the `custom.css` file all the time.

So, `<div id="left">` `background-colour` and `text-colour` should match `<section id="top-bar">` `background-colour` and `text-colour`.

Is it possible to dynamically set the CSS using JavaScript or similar?

Thanks

Comment: give a try and if you failed, add the code here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use js to get background-color of `#top_bar` element and add that color as background to other elements you want, in this case its siblings. Same is for text-color.

```js
var top_bar = $('#top-bar')
var bg = top_bar.css('background-color')
var color = top_bar.css('color')

top_bar.siblings().css({
  backgroundColor: bg,
  color: color
})
```

```css
section, div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}
#top-bar {
  background: #22B8F0;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="top-bar">
  Text
</section>
<section id="header">
 Text
</section>
<div id="left">
  Text
</div>
<section id="footer">
  Text
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a class to a parent element like the body element, such as preset1 etc, then select each element as children of that, like .preset1 #left
Then the only thing you have to change is one class, and there is no worry of resynchronisation.